# SQL Query to compare every entry in a column with every entry in another column

Tags: mysql

I have the following adjacency list of NIST 800-53 controls:

```
id    item        content         parent
1     Checklists  null            0
2     NIST80053   NIST 80053      1
3     AC          Access Control  2
4     1           POLICY..        3
5     2           ACCOUNT..       3
6     3           ACCESS..        3
```

The version of NIST I'm using (800-53a) is structured in a way where certain `item` will not be used.  Any such `item` would never have it's corresponding `item` mentioned in the `parent` column.  I am trying to design a SQL query that checks *each `id` to see if it is *ever* mentioned in the "parent" column, and display any successful results.

Right now the closest I've gotten was this simple statement, that does not work because it's only checking each row's id to that same rows parent (which will always be unequal, because an entry can't be it's own parent).  Instead of only getting unallocated items, the line returns the entire table:

```
 SELECT * FROM MySQL_IMPORTv2 where category_id != parent;
```

I am new to SQL, so hopefully I'm not missing something blatant here, but any help is appreciated.

Cheers,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Luckily this is really easy to do with an `exists()` statement. While I don't typically recommend qualifying on subqueries, `exsits()` are about as efficient as them come. If the subquery finds a result (any result that matches) it will immediately stop and return true.

The below query will return all four fields for any `id` that is listed as a parent of another `id`

```
select
  id
  , item
  , content
  , parent
from
  MySQL_IMPORTv2
where
  exists (
    select
      1
    from
      MySQL_IMPORTv2 M
    where
      M.parent = MySQL_IMPORTv2.id
  )
```

Comment: "If the subquery finds a result (any result that matches) it will immediately stop and return true." a co-related subquery can only do this if properly indexed. if not indexed this will run a full table scan for every record.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: That should only be true if we were using a `not exists()`, correct? The DB doesn't need to check every row, it only needs to find one. That's the whole reason they tend to be so much more efficient than `not exists()`. I did a quick check through the MySQL documentation and I didn't find anything that supports your comment.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbf557/1 check the execution plan.. type ALL indicating a full table scan.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Right, that shows that it isn't using an index, which by default is a full table scan. That doesn't show that the execution isn't short circuited by finding a single row.

Comment: Well i could not find annything in the MySQL documentation that exists() would short circuited by finding a single row.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` your table to itself using an `outer join` to find rows whose id is not used as a parent id in any other row.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a48f0d/4) for an example.

```
select
    p.*
from 
    MySQL_IMPORTv2 p                    -- Parent Row
    left outer join MySQL_IMPORTv2 c    -- Child Row
        on (p.id=c.parent)
where
    c.id is null
```

This query will take every row in your MySQL_IMPORTv2 table (with table alias `p`) and compare it with with every row in your table (with table alias `c`).  Because of the `left outer join`, the query will return every single row from `p`, regardless of if there is a match in `c`. However, wherever MySQL could not find a matching row in `c` from the join criteria, it will populate `c` with `null` values, so you can filter that by checking for a null value in `c`. Thus, you will find all the rows in your table that do not have a matching value in another column.

If you would like more information, you can take a look on Google for information about finding orphaned rows.

Answer (score 0):

> display any successful results

What is a successful result? A record with an id which also appears as a parent, or the parent records? The latter is likely to produce duplicate entries, do you want only one reported case for each matching parent? Do you want to see the original record alongside its parent?

What proportion of records don't have parents? What is the average number of children for a parent? What is the average depth of the leaf nodes? What indexes are defined on the table? While not essential to the functionality, these have a lot of bearing on the performance of the solution.

> id    item        content         parent
>
> ...
>
> SELECT * FROM MySQL_IMPORTv2 where category_id != parent;

What category_id?

A quick solution would be:

```
SELECT parent.id, parent.item, parent.content, GROUP_CONCAT(children.id)
FROM MySQL_IMPORTv2 AS children
INNER JOIN FROM MySQL_IMPORTv2 AS parents
ON children.parent_id=parent.id
GROUP BY parent.id, parent.item, parent.content
```

While to find the details of the children which have parents:

```
SELECT children.*
FROM MySQL_IMPORTv2 AS children
INNER JOIN FROM MySQL_IMPORTv2 AS parents
ON children.parent_id=parent.id
```

However looking at your data, it implies that all the records are children of the record with id=1, hence you might be asking for....

```
SELECT parent.id, parent.item, parent.content, GROUP_CONCAT(children.id)
FROM MySQL_IMPORTv2 AS children
INNER JOIN FROM MySQL_IMPORTv2 AS parents
ON children.parent_id=parent.id
AND children.parent_id>1
GROUP BY parent.id, parent.item, parent.content
```